# Left to right mark in regex (&#8206;) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, special-characters

I have this html (The text in Hebrew):

```
בדיקה בדיקה בדיקה&lrm;ניסיון ניסיון ניסיון
```

I want to remove the (`&lrm;`) by replacing it with space.

I tried to using regex like:

```js
$('#result').html($('#test').html().replace(/&lrm;/, ' '));
$('#result2').html($('#test2').html().replace(/©/, ' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">   
בדיקה בדיקה בדיקה&lrm;ניסיון ניסיון ניסיון
  </div>
<hr />
<div id="test2">   
בדיקה בדיקה בדיקה&copy;ניסיון ניסיון ניסיון
  </div>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
<hr />
<div id="result2"></div>
```

I added the copy example to show that I can replace the copy character because it's visible symbol. But How can I replace the left to right symbol?

Comment: Great example of how to ask a question (and it's an interesting one, too)

Comment: Try `$('#result').html($('#test').html().replace(/\u200E/, ' '));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you retrieve the HTML, apparently the LTR mark isn't being turned into a character entity, it's just Unicode character [`200E`](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200E).

So to allow for browsers that make it an entity and ones that don't, use an alternation between `&ltr;` and `\u200E`:

```js
var html = $('#test').html();
var rep = html.replace(/&lrm;|\u200E/gi, ' ');
$('#result').html(rep);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">   
בדיקה בדיקה בדיקה&lrm;ניסיון ניסיון ניסיון
</div>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
```

There I've also allowed for the entity to be in either upper case (`&LTR;`) or lower case (`&ltr;`), and added the `g` flag to replace it throughout the entire string (remove the `g` if you only wanted to replace the first one).